# How to execute two SQL commands in separate methods and roll back if the second raised an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, n-layer

I'm having hard time explaining the problem. But maybe I can do a better job in here.

In my 4-layer architecture application an online store with warehouse management system (A simple one) but lots of business rules.

Example 1:

1. The `Presentation Layer` calls the `Business Layer` to save the `Product`
2. The `BL.SaveProduct` method calls the `DL.SaveProduct` and then calls `DL.DecreaseBalance` method

If an exception occurs in `DL.DecreaseBalance`, the product will get saved violating the business rules and if I can't also violate the SoC by letting the DL handle both transactions

Is there is a design pattern or trick to help solve this problem ?

**My BL Method**

```
    public static bool CreateProduct(Product Product, out string Message)
    {
        using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                //validate
                if (Product.ValidateNew(out Message))
                {
                    //Check if sufficient balance exists
                    if (ProductBulksBL.BulkHasEnoughBalance(Product.BulkID, 1))
                    {
                        //save
                        ProductsDAL.CreateProduct(Product, out Message);

                            //log
                            ProductCreationLogDTO pLog = new ProductCreationLogDTO();
                            pLog.BulkID = Product.BulkID;
                            pLog.CreatedBy = UsersDAL.GetCurrentUserID();
                            pLog.TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;

                            ProductsDAL.LogCreatedProduct(pLog, out Message);

                                //update bulk balance 
                                ProductBulksDAL.UpdateBulkBalance(Product.BulkID, 1);
                                return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Message = "This product bulks doesn't have enough balance";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (TransactionException ex)
            {
                Message = ex.Message;
                transactionScope.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                transactionScope.Complete();
                transactionScope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Example DL Method Which All Built Using The Same Approach**

```
    public static void CreateProduct(Product Product, out string Message)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products (BulkID, CountryID, CityID, AreaID, Price, [Description], IPBan) VALUES (@BulkID, @CountryID, @CityID, @AreaID, @Price, @Description, @IPBan) ", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BulkID", Product.BulkID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Product.Price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Product.Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPBan", Product.IPBan);

                if (Product.Country != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", Product.Country.ID);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", DBNull.Value);

                if (Product.City != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", Product.City.ID);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", DBNull.Value);

                if (Product.Area != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaID", Product.Area.ID);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaID", DBNull.Value);

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Message = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

The TransactionScope isn't working

Comment: A database transaction?

Comment: Put your two calls into a `System.Transaction.TransactionScope` and only commit when **both** calls have succeeded - otherwise roll back

Comment: Yes. Well actually I used to run both sql statements in the same method inside a SQL Transaction Object to Roll Back in case of exceptions. But now that I'm looking at the design it violates the SoC and actually make it hard to modify Business Rules in the future. So I was hoping to do the same but roll back a method instead of rolling back a sql-command if you know what I mean

Comment: @marc_s, Haven't heard of it before. but based on the name looks like it might be the perfect solution for my problem. I will take a look on how to implement it and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @marc_s, I edited my post to include how I'm implementing it. I have an exception in the second method I call after I create the product. The product gets created but the application won't roll back.